# I'm having trouble with a multi-parameter typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Calling the 'bar' method of 'Foo', I get an error to the effect that it can't unify the types of 3 and 4 because they're overloaded literals.  But 'standaloneBar', which has seemingly the same type, works fine.  The difference must be the typeclass parameters, but I don't see why this prevents the unification.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Main where

class Foo a b where
  bar :: a -> b -> a

data Baz a = Baz a
instance Foo Int (Baz a) where
  bar i (Baz _) = i

standaloneBar :: a -> b -> a
standaloneBar x _ = x

main = do
  --putStrLn $ show $ bar 3 (Baz 4)          -- Can't unify
  putStrLn $ show $ standaloneBar 3 (Baz 4)  -- Works fine
  putStrLn $ show $ bar (3::Int) (Baz 4)     -- Works fine
  putStrLn $ show $ ((bar 3 (Baz 4)) :: Int) -- Works fine
```

If I add type annotations, then it works fine.

The way I understand unification here, even though 3 and 4 are ambiguous, they can still be unified:

```
*Util Delta Exp Tmi Util> :t 3
3 :: Num p => p
*Util Delta Exp Tmi Util> :t 4
4 :: Num p => p
*Util Delta Exp Tmi Util> :t 3 + 4
3 + 4 :: Num a => a
```

So why can't it do the same for 'bar'?

(I realize that a functional dependency here fixes the problem, but I'm specifically trying to allow for multiple instances that would be prevented by that.)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has to account for the possibility that, later on, and possibly in another module, someone defines something like

```
instance Foo Double (Baz a) where
  bar i (Baz _) = i + 1
```

In such case, `putStrLn $ show $ bar 3 (Baz 4)` could print `3` or `4.0` depending on the type of the literal `3`. Hence, it is rejected.

Note that the error mentions ambiguity, not the failure of unification:

```
prog.hs:16:14: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

In your GHCi session, `> :t 3 + 4` can output `Num a => a` since it is possible for that to report a polymorphic type. If you run `> :t show (3+4)` the result is a monomorphic `String`, and that forced GHCi to choose a specific type `a` to instantiate the constants with. It happens that `Num` receives special care by Haskell, and some "default" types are tried when that happens. This is indeed called "defaulting", and only happens with a few `Prelude` classes. It does not apply to custom classes such as your `Foo`, where instead an ambiguity is reported.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation!  I wonder if you might suggest another way to do this that won't require a ton of explicit annotations.  What I'm trying to do is allow for the creation, for any given type, an open-ended set of delta types that represent changes to values of that type.  That's why I wanted to leave off the functional dependency.  I suspect type families might have an answer, but I have learn about those first.

Comment: @gregorymichaeltravis Do you really need the same delta type to apply to many types. I can see why you do not want the fundep `a -> b`, but maybe `b -> a` can be added without losing too much?

Comment: No, you're totally right, that hadn't occurred to me.  The delta only needs to apply to one type.

Answer (score 0):

`standaloneBar` doesn't really have the same type. It is `a -> b -> a`, which is the same type as the type given for `bar` in the **class**. But the problem isn't that `bar 3 (Baz 4)` is failing to match the general type from the class, rather it is that `bar 3 (Baz 4)` is failing to uniquely determine an **instance**.

When type classes are involved, type inference doesn't just have to determine that there is *some* assignment of type variables that is well-typed, it has to actually decide which specific instance will be selected<sup>1</sup>. Different instances could have very different behaviour, so the choice matters.

The type the compiler infers for the use of `bar` in your code is `bar :: (Foo a (Baz b), Num a, Num b, Show a) => a -> Baz b -> a` (the `Show` constraint comes from the result being passed to `show`). Now, the version of `bar` from the `Foo Int (Baz a)` instance has type `Int -> Baz a -> Int`, which obviously *does* unify with your usage of `bar`. But other possible instances might also unify. There could be `Foo Double (Baz a)`, or `Foo a (Baz Float)`, or any number of other possibilities.

It would be possible for the compiler to work by picking `Foo Int (Baz a)`, since that't the only instance in scope and it *does* fit. However the rules of the language are designed so that the compiler actually should not consider the instances which are in scope when it determines which instance is needed! It is required that the appropriate instance is uniquely clear from the context of the call, and *then* the compiler checks whether such an instance is actually available. So there would need to be a polymorphic `Foo a (Baz b)` instance in scope for this code to work. And indeed, if I replace your instance with:

```
instance Foo a (Baz b) where
  bar i _ = i
```

Then your code compiles and runs without error!

So your original code isn't specific enough about the types to uniquely determine that `Foo Int (Baz b)` is the required instance, so the compiler reports errors about ambiguous types. The problem isn't that it your use of `bar` doesn't unify with `a -> b -> a`, or even that it doesn't unify with `Int -> Baz b -> Int`; it *does* unify with both. Rather the problem is that it isn't *specific* to the type `Int -> Baz b -> Int`. Adding additional type information resolves that, and is required.

The reason for this language design decision is so that variations in which instances are in scope (say by adding and removing imports) can never change the meaning of valid code into other valid code. If you remove a required instance the code will stop working, and if you add a conflicting instance the code will cause an error, but if you have code that compiles with 2 instances in scope by using 1 of them, you can never make it continue to work and use the other one solely by changing your imports. The intent is that the choice of instance should be inherently required by your code supplied by the programmer, the choice should not be just accidentally made by the compiler.

---

It's worth noting that there is a major exception to this rule of instance selection not being based on which instances are actually in scope<sup>2</sup>. That is type defaulting.

Simple expressions involving numeric literals would almost always be ambiguous under the rules I described above. An example is `show $ 1 + 2`. The `+` and the `show` in that have differing behaviour for different instances (`+` isn't even fully associative for floating point numbers for example!), so by the reasoning above this code should be invalid, and the programmer should be required to write something like `show $ 1 + (2 :: Int)`.

The language designers considered this to be too onerous, so the defaulting rules were defined. They're described in more detail in [the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), but basically they allow ambiguous type variables to be defaulted if there is a constraint involving one of the "numeric" type classes (like `Num`, `Integral`, etc) from the Prelude, and the ambiguous type does not have any type class constraints *except* those involving classes defined in the Prelude. If these (very conservative) constraints are met, then some default types will be tried (the default list of default types is `Integer, Double`, but it can be customised; the conditions under which defaulting will be tried cannot be customised, however), and if one of those allows instances to be found for all constraints then the code will be accepted with the compiler choosing those instances for you.

This means that the ambiguous type variables `a` and `b` in `bar :: (Foo a (Baz b), Num a, Num b, Show a) => a -> Baz b -> a` cannot be defaulted; they're involved in the constraint `Foo a (Baz b)`, which is not for a class defined in the Prelude.

But when you use `standaloneBar` (or you use my more polymorphic `Foo a (Baz b)` instance above), then the only constraints that the compiler is unable to resolve are `(Num a, Num b, Show a)`. Here all of the constraints are Prelude classes, and `Num` is a "numeric class", so the compiler tries `Integer` for both `a` and `b`, which works and allows the code to compile.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless the type class constraint can be "passed on" in the signature of the caller, but the caller here is `main :: IO ()`, so that option isn't available.

<sup>2</sup> If you enable further extensions such as `OverlappingInstances` then there are more exceptions, but I'm not describing that here.

Comment: Thank you as well for this very clear answer.  In addition to understanding it better, your first footnote made me realize that needing annotations probably won't be a burden most of the time.

Comment: One thing I am curious about -- your fully polymorphic version unifies with the call site, but so does the hypothetical `Foo Double (Baz a)` and `Foo a (Baz Float)` -- why does this not cause an ambiguity?  Is it because the fully polymorphic one includes/subsumes the two more specific ones?

Comment: @gregory Yes, because it's invalid to have overlapping instances (without extensions) when the polymorphic instance exists then no more-specific one can exist. So when the compiler tries to solve the polymorphic constraint `Foo a (Bar b)` it only has to look for a polymorphic instance; if it finds a general one, then no specific ones can exist so there's no ambiguity, and if it doesn't find a general one then it can throw an error because it would be ambiguous.